# SQL query and join table

Tags: php, sql

I am given an array of group IDs.
I have a table that has these integer fields:

```
id, node_id and group_id
```

In this table, `node_id` is not unique and `group_id` is not unique.

I need to locate each unique `nodeID` that has **all** of the given `groupIDs`. (I want just one instance of each `node_id`.)

```
//????
$groups_str = implode(',', $groups);
$query = "SELECT node_id FROM group_nodes
WHERE ............ IN({$groups}) 
...........";
```

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` to select node_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT node_id 
FROM group_nodes
WHERE group_id IN ($groups)
group by node_id
having count(distinct group_id) = $arraySize
```

Comment: Got a similar query working today. This solution worked great. Thanks.